# Kendo - как задать класс при инициализации таблиы

Tags: kendo

Вывожу таблицу следующим образом:

```
    <div id="ordersList"
       data-class="paging-fix zebra"
       data-role="uigrid"
       data-scrollable="false"
       data-checkbox="true"
       data-pageable="true"
       data-class="zebra"
       data-bind="source: orders, events : { selectionChanged: selectionChanged }"
       data-columns="[
          <% if (isSeller) { %>
          { title: 'Покупатель', field: 'buyerName' },
          { title: 'GLN покупателя', field: 'buyerGln' },
          <% } else { %>
          { title: 'Продавец', field: 'sellerName' },
          { title: 'GLN продавца', field: 'sellerGln' },
          <% } %>
          { title: 'Номер заказа', templateId: 'col-template' },
          { title: 'Дата заказа', templateId: 'col1-template' },
          { title: 'Место доставки', field: 'deliveryAddress' },
          { title: 'GLN точки доставки', field: 'deliveryGln' },
          { title: 'Сумма без НДС', field: 'sum' },
          { title: 'Сумма с НДС', field: 'vatSum' },
          { title: 'Статус', field: 'status' }
          <% if (!isSeller) { %>
          ,{ title: '', templateId: 'col2-template', width: 35 }
          <% } %>
          ]">
     </div>
```

Пробую добавлять так: `data-class="paging-fix zebra"`.

Не работает.

Comment: Где пример в доджо?

Comment: не думаю что он здесь нужен